# Tex fonts for the Voynich manuscript language

Tags: fonts, symbols, languages, font-encodings

I would like to put an epigraph from the Voynich manuscript (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voynich_manuscript).

Unfortunately, I don't know which tex-fonts I can use.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: the wikipedia article links to [this font](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/voynich) which you could use from luatex or xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you! But I suppose that most of the publishers use latex so it would be a problem with luatex or xetex...

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal then most likely any non standard font is a problem. You probably should edit your question to make your requirements more clear, and why you can not use xelatex and whether you can use any font not already specified by the publisher stylesheet.

Comment: You can create the fragment with xetex/luatex, output as a standalone pdf (i.e., without a regular page around it), and include that pdf as a graphic in your main document.